# ¿como quito los bordes del iframe en una pagina web?

Tags: html5

Tengo esta linea de código, y en la página principal, no aparecen los bordes del iframe pero cuando le doy a el enlace para llamar otra página, ahí si aparecen las líneas. Quisiera saber cómo quitarlas. Gracias

```
<center>
<iframe name='nombre' width="1000" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</center>
```

Comment: ¿Tiene alguna captura de pantalla que muestre mejor lo que nos está diciendo en su pregunta? No me queda claro a qué se refiere con "bordes"...

Comment: "cuando le doy a el enlace", te refieres a un enlace dentro del iFrame? es algo confusa, agrega una imagen como comenta Mauricio.

Answer (score 1):

tu código es correcto, sólo que la palabra `frameBorder` lleva B mayúscula..
Ese código funciona para HTML 4, si estás escribiendo código para HTML 5, mejor utiliza `seamless='seamless'` ya que ya no soporta `frameBorder`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar css para eso, así:

```
<style>
iframe{
border:none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando yo hago un iframe de una web a pantalla completa lo hago así. A ver si te sirve.

```html
<body>
<iframe src="http://es.stackoverflow.com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
</iframe>
</body>
```

Actualmente lo estoy usando en una web y me funciona muy bien.